# Linked view modes in Windows File Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

All of a sudden the view modes for `This PC` and `D:` in Windows Explorer have become linked together.

If I change the view mode (tiles, details, list, etc) in any one of these places it changes the other one as well.

This does not happen with any other folders. Restarting did not help.

Comment: This would only happen if `This PC` and `D:` were the same folder type.  If that is the case then this behavior is intended.

Comment: They are not the same folder type though. Also this started happening just a few hours ago, before which they had different views.

Comment: And now it's back to normal ... different views can be set on each